# update markers without reloading the web page google maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

First of all I apologize for my poor English but I can not find the answer to my question on all French forums.

I am developing an application that is to make real-time tracking of a fleet of vehicles.

I'm at the end of this application but I have a problem. I can not update my markers without reloading my web page.

I tried with `settimeout()` but it still charging my map

here is my code thank you for your help.

ps: when completed this application will be available in open source

```
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Exemple" href="theme.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Geonano V1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html{height: 100%}
            body{height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px}
            #EmplacementDeMaCarte{height: 100%}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialisation() {
                var tableauLieux = [ 
//here I have a loop in php to get my markers in my database

["Paris",     48.86110, 2.34459],
["Versailles",     48.78199, 2.11045]


                ];
                var optionsCarte = {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("EmplacementDeMaCarte"), optionsCarte);
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < tableauLieux.length; i++) {
                    var Lieu = tableauLieux[i];
                    var pointLieu = new google.maps.LatLng(Lieu[1], Lieu[2]);
                    bounds.extend(pointLieu);
                    var marqueurLieu = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pointLieu,
                        map: maCarte,
                        title: Lieu[0],
                        icon : Lieu[3],
                        clickable: true

                    });
                    //création de l'info-bulle
                    var infoBulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: Lieu[0]//ici on peut mettre des balises HTML
                    });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marqueurLieu, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(Lieu[i][0]);
            infoBulle .open(maCarte,marqueurLieu);
            }); 
                }

                maCarte.fitBounds(bounds);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialisation);
            setInterval("initialisation()", 5000); 
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="EmplacementDeMaCarte"></div>



    </body>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="120; URL=http://localhost/geonano.php">
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget that to use the API for real-time tracking of vehicles you need an Enterprise licence (client ID) and it's against the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_2) to use a free API key.

Comment: use english to code, you never know who will work on this code next..

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to request a ressource(may be a PHP-script) which returns the data for the markers(tableauLieux) using AJAX.

Once you got the response, remove the current markers and create the new markers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you're redrawing the map each 5 second with all the markers.

Bascily what you want to do is store your marker in an array that you can loop through at a later time to change their lat and lng. Clear them from the map, change the information and then put them back on the map. Changing the information is going to need some ajax.

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

Comment: thank you for your help I understand your method but I can not implement it in my javascript can you help me?

thank you again

Comment: make a function that you call each 5 seconds that does your PHP loop to get the markers from your DB. 

I think clearing the previous markers would be best.

map.clearOverlays();

then just redraw your markers like you did before. This way you don't have to save them and no update is needed

Comment: You should have an array of your markers that you can loop through and clear them. I don't think map.clearOverlays(); works in v3.

Answer (score 0):

a good way to do that is using something like

```
refreshIntervalId = setInterval("requestPoints()", 4000);

function requestPoints() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'{% url 'gpstracking.ajax.request_tracks' %}',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            vehicles: vehicles
        },
        success: function (positions) {
            updatePoints (positions);
        }
    });
}

function updatePoints (positions) {
    console.debug('updating markers');
    var lttd;
    var lgtd;
    for (var i=0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        lttd = positions[i].latitude;
        lgtd = positions[i].longitude;
        position = map.createPosition({
            lat: lttd,
            lng: lgtd,
        });
        markers[positions[i].registration].setPosition(position);
    };
    if (positions.length > 1) {
        //map.fitZoom();
    } else {
        map.setCenter (lttd, lgtd);
    }
}
```